# How to group objects that have the same lists of child objects?

Tags: c#, list, linq, group-by

I am trying to group a list of objects, the objects have a property which is a list. When using the following expression it does not group the objects together which have a list, presumably because when it checks the equality of each list, it doesn't match - even though the content is the same.

I know this is the issue, as if I stop grouping the list, the code outputs two items rather than three.

How can I adapt my expression so that it correctly groups the first two items (which are identical) into one?

```
public class Item {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<ChildItem> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildItem {
  public string ChildItemName { get; set; }
}
```

```
var items = new List<Item> {
  new Item {
    Id = "00001",
    Name = "My Item",
    Children = new List<ChildItem> {
      new ChildItem { ChildItemName = "string 1" },
      new ChildItem { ChildItemName = "string 2" },
    }
  },
  new Item {
    Id = "00001",
    Name = "My Item",
    Children = new List<ChildItem> {
      new ChildItem { ChildItemName = "string 1" },
      new ChildItem { ChildItemName = "string 2" },
    }
  },
  new Item {
    Id = "00002",
    Name = "My Second Item",
    Children = new List<ChildItem> {
      new ChildItem { ChildItemName = "string 3" },
    }
  }
};

var result =
  from c in items
  group c by new
  {
    c.Id,
    c.Name,
    c.Children,
  }
  into gcs
  select new Item()
  {
    Id = gcs.Key.Id,
    Name = gcs.Key.Name,
    Children = gcs.Key.Children
  };
```

Comment: Override `Equals` & `GetHashCode` for `ChildItem`.

Comment: Do not listen to @JohnathanBarclay advise, unless you are 100% sure what you are doing, and what does those two overrides mean, and 100% sure that this will not collide with anything else or cause problems in other parts of the code. Depending on your domain logic, you may want to "compare" the same things in different way in different places. Those `overrides` won't let you do that. Also, there's a lot of code (libraries) that rely on .Equals and .GetHashCode for various things, and and overriding .Equals may cause subtle errors. Use `IEqualityComparer<>` from Olivier's answer. It's safer.

Comment: I've edited the title to make it a little bit clearer. I think that "Group .. with IEnumerable Properties" didn't tell what you wanted to achieve. Also, we usually don't include keywords in the title unless necessary, so I removed C# and LINQ tags from the title (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). Of course, feel free to re-edit the title, or even roll it back if you want.

Comment: Why don't you compare the objects by `Id` instead of by `Children`? It is more efficient to compare `int`s than `List`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If items with the same Id have identical names and collections, you can just group by Id and then take the first item of the group

```
IEnumerable<Item> uniqueItems = items
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

You don't need to put everything into the group key.

---

Since, according to your comment, the `Id` does not guarantee uniqueness, you must provide your own definition of what "equal" means. You can do this by implementing your own equality comparers.

An implementation for `ChildItem` as singleton, since it will be used repeatedly in `ItemEqualityComparer.Equals`.

```
class ChildItemEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ChildItem>
{
    public static readonly ChildItemEqualityComparer Instance =
        new ChildItemEqualityComparer(); // Create singleton.
    private ChildItemEqualityComparer() { } // Hide constructor.

    public bool Equals(ChildItem x, ChildItem y) =>
        String.Equals(x.ChildItemName, y.ChildItemName);
    public int GetHashCode(ChildItem childItem) =>
        childItem.ChildItemName?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
}
```

An implementation for `Item`:

```
class ItemEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name &&
            Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x.Children, y.Children,
                ChildItemEqualityComparer.Instance);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item item)
    {
        int hash = 43;
        unchecked {
            hash = 17 * hash + (item.Id?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
            hash = 17 * hash + (item.Name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
            foreach (ChildItem childItem in item.Children) {
                hash = 17 * hash + ChildItemEqualityComparer.Instance.GetHashCode(childItem);
            }
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

And the query:

```
var result = items.Distinct(new ItemEqualityComparer());
```

This yields 2 items.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the GroupBy expression like this

```
items.GroupBy(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: Yeah I can write the syntax slightly differently, but the issue regarding list equality remains, I don't want to group by ID, I want to group by all properties in the object.

Comment: are you talking about getting unique elements or grouping?

Comment: I have items in the array which are identical, and I want to eliminate the duplicates, but because the object has an IEnumerable/List, the group by is not eliminating the duplicates.

Comment: Group by is not supposed to eliminate any data you have.. simply group them together. If you are looking to get rid of Duplicates, then you have to do it a bit differently.

Comment: @TomMcClean A group by never eliminates anything, it checks equal or not, not more. On the other hand, if objects aren't equal there are no duplicates.
You seem to have different definitions of beeing equal.

Comment: Yeah there is a difference between what I consider "equal" and what is due to the references, but when I remove the list properties from the group by, it does eliminate the duplicates, was hoping there may be a simple thing I could add to my query to check the lists by content rather than reference.

Comment: You can write your own Equals method in your Item class to compare the two objects (you might have to get a bit creative about the list)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to eliminate the duplicates you can just transform the collection to `HashSet` and back.

```
items.ToHashSet().ToList();
```

You will want to override the default implementation of `GetHashCode` though, to make sure that it is calculated using the fields of `Item`.

Comment: ToHashSet takes IEqualityComparer as second argument. It's much safer to use that instead of overriding GHC, unless you are 100% sure that such override is safe (for instance, that 'item' class is your private implementation detail and is not used in any other sorting/dictionary/etc in another place, and so on)

Comment: Good point @quetzalcoatl. In this case it seems that `Item` is just Tom's implementation, but in other cases it makes much more sense to use the `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have to use ChildItem class (instead of a simple string) you
   can consider implementing IEqualityComparer for ChildItem. This enables the use of
   (System.Linq) SequenceEqual method.

```
ProductA[] storeA = { new ProductA { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                       new ProductA { Name = "orange", Code = 4 } };

ProductA[] storeB = { new ProductA { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                       new ProductA { Name = "orange", Code = 4 } };

bool equalAB = storeA.SequenceEqual(storeB);
```

2. Then you can think about implementing IEquatable interface in Item class.

> The IEquatable interface defines the Equals method, which
>   determines the equality of instances of the implementing type

In Equals method you can use SequenceEqual to check equality Children which is described above.

3.Lastly you can use (System.Linq) Distinct() method to get unique objects for items.

```
IEnumerable<Item> noduplicates = items.Distinct();
```

Please check out:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.8

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8